# Laravel Asset Pipeline conditional JavaScript

Tags: laravel-4, asset-pipeline

Since the [Asset Pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline/) package for Laravel doesn't allow you to conditionally add scripts/stylesheets to the page, what is the best way of doing this?

I've got one JavaScript file which is a set of files concatenated together that are included on every page, providing us with a library file. What I now need to do is add another JavaScript file for certain pages (all of which use the same template).

My current plan is to extend the `BaseController` to add an array of scripts/styles that can be dynamically attached to the template if there are any items. But surely there is a better way that is part of the Asset Pipeline packages?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't make use of `asset-pipeline`, but the solution I use is the `@parent` directive in Blade templates.

On my site I have several `js` and several `css` that I need in every page (eg. `Twitter bootstrap`) and I have a `Blade layout` that includes those.

Then on certain pages (my app is an analytic app) I need to include page-specific assets (eg. a charting library).

On my layout, therefore, I have:

```
@section('js')
{{ HTML::script('js/a.js') }}
@show

@section('css')
{{ HTML::style('css/a.css') }}
@show
```

And then on a particular page, I have:

```
@extends('layouts.site')

@section('js')
@parent
{{ HTML::script('js/b.js') }}
@stop

@section('css')
@parent
{{ HTML::style('css/b.css')
@stop
```

This works great for me.  The sub pages in my app are very specific about which extra assets they need so controlling them this way is very workable.